# Cordova android app not installed after app source moved to another pc

Tags: android, cordova

I had moved my Android Cordova app to another PC and after installing all requirements (Apache Ant, JDK, Android SDK, Cordova) on new PC I run:

```
cordova build android
```

and it had been built successfully.

notice: I did not change app source (config.xml - www - plugins - platforms - hooks )

The problem is that when I tried to install it on my Nexus 5 phone (which already my app was installed on it with my older PC build) it throw error:
*app not installed*

**So I had to uninstalled older app and install new one however on usual situation new app replaced older app automatically.**

What did I wrong?

Comment: Hi...i want to know why phonegap is prefered over native app development though it is having some limitations? dont say cost and time? want to know some technical advantages?

Comment: Actually i do not PREFERRED cordova over native app. but in my situation I need to build my app in IOS & android & windows phone platforms and using cordova + framework7 seems really logical for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have to uninstall previous because both app having different signature of pc sdk so you can't install  app from other pc before uninstalling current application

Comment: Is any solution for that?! I suppose it can be a nightmare if for any reason my PC broke up. what should my app users do for installing my new app version?!

Comment: @EmadEmami No you can not install new apk from other pc without uninstalling older app

Comment: @jankigadhiya so what you want ? i just giving him a solution

Comment: @jankigadhiya if you have any anser please give him solution

Comment: @jankigadhiya yes but no one can read comment if some one find this question rather , they finding proper answer and this is proper answer if you have any good answer please give reference link or post answer with technical specification.

Comment: @EmadEmami Please accept answer you have got your answer , it would help for other to understand this issue

Comment: another question: If on older PC i just change OS from windows 8 to 10 does signature of PC SDK change or it will be fine?

Comment: @EmadEmami if you are updating your pc through official channel there is no problem if you are format your pc and re-install all thing than you have to reinstall app after uninstalling your application